# R: Avoid list element with max function in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I have the following problem working with a dataframe.
I use

```
f11<-as.data.frame(cbind(row.names(f[,14:21]),apply(f[,14:21],1,function(x) names(f[,14:21])[which(x==max(x,na.rm=FALSE))])))
```

to get the column name that contains the maximum value within a range of coumns and write it into a seperate dataframe. However, if all values in the range are "NA" it pastes a list-element with all the column names. Is there a way to get it to insert "unknown" instead. The NA's are important and need to be preserved.

Hope you can help.

EDITS:
Here a small example:

```
a<-c(NA,1,NA)
b<-c(NA,NA,NA)
c<-c(1,NA,NA)
d<-data.frame(a,b,c)
d1<-as.data.frame(cbind(row.names(d[,1:3]),apply(d[,1:3],1,function(x) names(d[,1:3])[which(x==max(x,na.rm=TRUE))])))
d1$V3<-ifelse(nchar(d1$V2)>1,"unknown",d1$V2) #my idea on how to replace the list with "unknown"
write.csv(d1,file="test.csv")
```

I want to get rid of the warning message when saving the document nut have d1$V2 look exactly like this.  In d[,1:3] there is always only one value while there are two NA's

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ifelse` to check inside `apply` if all values are missing (`all(is.na(x))`). In your example:

```
a <- c(NA, 1, NA)
b <- c(NA, NA, NA)
c <- c(1, NA, NA)
d <- data.frame(a,b,c)
d1 <- apply(d, 1, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), "unknown",
                                     names(d)[ which.max(x) ]) )
d1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(row.names(d), d1))
```

Bonus: you can use `which.max(x)` instead of `which(max(x) == x)`. It handles NA's too.

And make your code more legible.